# How do I stop my test from automatically logging me out when I'm using cypress?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I'm currently using Cypress to test my application. This particular test I'm talking about needs to fill in a form for a financing flow, divided in 3 different views in my application.

This is my test's code:

```js
describe('finance process logged', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.setCookie('token', 'Bearer ' + token)
      cy.intercept('GET', '**/me', { fixture: 'me.json' }).as('getUser')
      cy.intercept('PUT', '**/me', { fixture: 'me.json' }).as('putMe')
      cy.intercept('PATCH', '**/me/gdpr_consents', gdpr_consents).as('patchGDPR')
      cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v1/payment_methods', {
        fixture: 'purchase-payment-methods.json',
      }).as('getPaymentMethods')
      cy.route({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '**/api/v1/orders',
        status: 200,
        response: {
          uid: '12345',
          status: 'init',
        },
      }).as('newOrder')
      cy.route('GET', '**/api/v1/orders/12345', 'fixture:purchase-order.json').as('getOrder')
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/v1/orders/248062de9f2c39e6/payments', 'fixture:financing-payment.json').as('getPayments')
      
    })
    it('finance process ok', () => {
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/v1/orders/ca3f258f588ef610/payments', {
        fixture: 'finance-payments-response.json',
      }).as('postPayments')
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/v1/transaction_financings/a60ceba307f0dcde/prescorings', {
        fixture: 'finance-update-transaction-response.json',
      }).as('postPrescoring')
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/v1/transaction_financings/a60ceba307f0dcde/details', {
        fixture: 'purchase-customer-details.json',
      }).as('postDetails')
      cy.visit('/sportage/sportage-2020-1-6-crdi-isg-6mt-mhev-urban/4c51ed/payment-choose', Cypress.config('VISIT_OPTIONS'))
      cy.getByDataCy('purchase-page').should('be.visible')
      cy.getByDataCy('request-finance').click()
      cy.getByDataCy('financing-page').should('be.visible')
      cy.getByDataCy('start-financing-button').should('be.visible').click()
      cy.getByDataCy('personal-finance-data').should('be.visible')
      cy.getByDataCy('email-input').should('be.visible').should('have.attr', 'disabled')
      fillPersonalData()
      cy.getByDataCy('data-authorization-check').check()
      cy.getByDataCy('button-personal-data-next').click()
      cy.getByDataCy('form-contact-data').should('be.visible')
      fillContactData()
      cy.getByDataCy('button-contact-data-next').click()
      cy.getByDataCy('form-employment-data').should('be.visible')
      fillEmploymentData()
      cy.getByDataCy('button-next-financing').click()
      cy.wait('@postPrescoring')
      cy.wait('@customerOrder')
      cy.wait('@getTariff')
      cy.getByDataCy('finance-requested-page').should('be.visible')
    })
```

})

The test fails by logging out when it switches tabs in the front (from one form to another), specifically after clicking **cy.getByDataCy('button-personal-data-next').click()**, and therefore fails in the next step
**cy.getByDataCy('form-contact-data').should('be.visible')**.

In my web application, it doesn't log out the client, so I wanted to know how I can prevent it from sing-out the user.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird. You can try placing code for different tabs into different `it` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of `cy.route()` calls which are deprecated, they should be `cy.intercept()`.

See [cy.route()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route)

> ⚠️ cy.server() and cy.route() are deprecated in Cypress 6.0.0. In a future release, support for cy.server() and cy.route() will be removed. Consider using cy.intercept() instead. See our guide on Migrating cy.route() to cy.intercept()

The `cy.route()` command was always preceded by `cy.server()` which you do not have, so probably these commands are doing nothing.

Change them to `cy.intercept()` and you might fix your problem.

Comment: Hi! I've changed the cy.route() for cy.intercept(), but it still logs me out